How to access the exposed method (defineExpose) through querySelector
How do I access refs through document.querySelector?
I use nuxtjs 3 when I want to access refs using querySelector I was able to do that in npm run dev mode, but after creating the project or exporting it npm run generate this method does not work...
el.value.querySelector(".myComponetShow").__vueParentComponent.exposed.show();

Is there a specific way to do the same idea? Also, are there any suggestions?
i have layout :
<template>
  <div class="my-layout">
    <slot></slot>
    <button @click="show()">show</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
function show() {
// ??
  document.querySelector("myElementShow").exposed.show();
}
</script>

page :
<template>
  <div class="my-page">
    <h1>PAGE</h1>

    <myComponetShow>
    </myComponetShow>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
</script>

myComponetShow :
<template>
  <div ref="ele" class="myComponetShow">

  <div v-if="show">
    <!-- Some Code -->
  </div>
  <div v-else>
  <!-- Some Code -->
  </div>

  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
const show = ref(false);
defineExpose({
  show() {
    show.value = true;
  }
});
</script>



Consider explaining your case. What do you need this for? You can totally expect that internals like __vueParentComponent aren't available in production

As a rule of thumb, do not relay and use methods or variables starting with underline (like '__vueParentComponent). These are supposed to be private. As a hint, the sharing state between parents and N-Level children can be achieved via the Provide/Inject mechanism.

There are a lot of cleaner and simpler ways to communicate between components in Vue, like events/props, provide/inject, stores etc.
In this particular case the simplest solution is probably provide/inject:
Layout
<script setup>
const isShown = ref(false)
provide('isShown', isShown)
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="isShown = true">show</button>
<template>

MyComponetShow
<script setup>
const isShown = inject('isShown')
</script>

<template>
  <div v-if="isShown">
    <!-- Some Code -->
  </div>
  <div v-else>
    <!-- Some Code -->
  </div>
</template>


you can access the exposed via ref
<template>
  <div class="my-page">
    <h1>PAGE</h1>
    <myComponetShow ref="myComponent" />
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
const myComponent = ref();

const show = async () => {
    await nextTick();
    myComponent.value.show();
}

show();
</script>

And this is how I would expose it
<script setup lang="ts">
const show_ = ref(false); // renaming to _show to avoid duplicate with component method

const show = () => {
   show_.value = true;
}

defineExpose({
  show
});
</script>

